# How to find Certificate signing request information?

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl, troubleshooting

I need to update certificates for the Apache servers (Linux Servers RHEL6) and it appears our team doesn't know the correct information for the CSR.  Is there a way to find the correct information from the server?

**Output from the server below:**

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  44  month 2   2014 ca-bundle.crt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 33   month 2   2014 ca-bundle.trust.crt
-rw-------. 1 root root 1155 month 14  2013 localhost.crt
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what information exactly you are talking about. The Subject? You can get that from a browser or with openssl you can get it like so:

```
openssl x509 -in localhost.crt -text -noout
```

Comment: I am trying to find out with what information CSR was created and use the same.

Comment: localhost.crt doesn't have that information.

Comment: okay location of that file was different from this one.  I got the information with that command.  Thanks